Experimenting with "high voltage" positive and "high voltage" negative using an ignition coil
Experimenting with "high voltage" positive and "high voltage" negative using an ignition coil.
I would like to compare a high-voltage positive to a ‘high-voltage’ negative using an ignition coil. Please refer to the example / original setup image for more details.

Please note that in this simple setup, the 9V battery shown in the image will be replaced with a PWM that will operate within a range of 0 to 150kHz, from 0-35V, and from 0-8A.
I am curious to know if it would be as simple as reversing the input polarities to cause the high-voltage positive to become a ‘high-voltage’ negative. **If not, could someone advise me on how I could go about changing the high-voltage polarity on the secondary output of the ignition coil to become negative?
How I can verify the voltage polarity with out the high voltage damaging my multi-meter.

You should use a "high voltage" (some 40-50 kV) probe with the multimeter, otherwise, it should "blow". Use only 12-16 V for your power supply.

Presuming the schematic for +ve HV is as follows:

It's only a question of reversing the polarity at the primary to obtain -ve HV.

